# Getting set of Integers from a JSONArray in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, set

I have the following `java` code where I am trying to pull a set of integers from a `JSONArray` object. How can I do so?

```
JSONObject actionDetail = new JSONObject("myJsonOject");

int personId = actionDetail.getInt("personId");
JSONArray addressIds = actionDetail.getJSONArray("addressIds");

Action action = new Action();

action.setPersonId(personId); //working ok

action.setAddressIds(): //todo - how to get list of ints from the JsonArray?
```

Note that the type of `addressIds` field is: `Set<Integer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try cast Object to Integer in stream.

```
action.setAddressIds(addressIds.toList().stream().map(k -> (Integer) k).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
Set<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, addressIds.length())
        .mapToObj(addressIds::get)
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```